Is http2 over websocket a good idea to change client/server roles after the client's connection to the server?
I am investigating a proposed connection standard called Uplink (As of writing this question, it is working draft 24.06) described by ONVIF . In a nutshell the proposed specification suggests a connection sequence that gets initiated by a client towards a remote server and later gets upgraded to http2 and the roles get swapped, as the client becomes the server.
There are 2 flavors, Native and Websocket h2c-reverse.


I am questioning the necessity of the websocket. Why is websocket needed?
One thing that came to my mind is to use HTTP CONNECT from the client side and later on upgrade the server initiating the http2 upgrade sequence. My assumptions is that this way hasn't been picked because it makes the assumption that proxies, servers will support CONNECT. A google on this subject makes me think that CONNECT support varies a lot.
The native over websocket seems more efficient since there is no websocket framing. What is the benefit of this overhead?
Technically I don't see a problem with the Native one but I am wondering if this would cause problems in the http aware firewalls/routers since we swap the client/server roles implicitly. For example, all the sudden the client is receiving http2 preface and maybe this is stopped at carrier level. Otherwise, the client and the server can do what ever they want as part of the specification. I would appreciate if someone explain the advantages of using websocket.
Are there other alternatives that can support this use case?
